# How to convert day into year month week then days

Tags: c, error-handling, runtime-error, programming-languages

here I calculated months with only 30 days but I want to calculate month like 
    January  31, February  28 or 29, April 30 like that

How logically I achieve that. Plz help me solve this problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int in_days, years, months, days, extra, week;
printf("Enter number of days : ");
scanf("%d", &in_days);
If(in_day>1460){
   years = in_days/365;
   extra = in_days%365;
   months = extra/30; 
   days = extra%30;
   printf("%d days is same as %d years + %d months + %d days", in_days, years, months, days);
} 
else If(in_day<1460 & & in_day>=365){
       years = in_days/365;
       extra = in_days%365;
       months = extra/30;
       days = extra%30;
       printf("%d days is same as %d years + %d months + %d days", in_days, years, months, days);
  } 
else If(in_day<365){
       months = in_day/30;
       days = in_day%30;
       printf("%d days is same as %d months + %d days", in_days, months, days);
  } 
else If(in_day<30){
       week= in_day/7;
       days = week%7;
       printf("%d days is same as %d months + %d days", in_days, week, days);
  } 
getch() ;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to calculate it yourself, find a library that does it for you. Dates and times are much harder than it seems because of all the weird corner-cases (like leap-years and leap-seconds and not all months being the same etc.).

Comment: C is case-sensitive. Seeing all those `If` in the code means it won’t compile.

Comment: Define an array `int month_lengths[]` containing the values 31, 28, 31, 30, ... .  Then you can write a simple loop that will let you compute, for example, that day 74 is the 74 - 31 - 28 = 15th day of March.  Then you can make a simple modification for leap years.

Comment: One big problem is that you can't really check for leap-years, since all you have is a "number of days" without any start or end. The "number of days" have to be relative to some other date, or you don't know which years would be leap years. You could only approximate by saying every fourth year is a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

You can add function to calculate #months

```
#include<stdio.h>

int cal_months(int *days){
    int months_arr[] = {31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365}, i, months = 1;
    if(*days < 31){
        return 0;
    }
    for(i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        if(*days < months_arr[i]){
            *days -= months_arr[i-1];
            break;
        }else{
            months ++;
        }
    }
    return months;
}

int main()
{
    int in_days, years, months, days, extra, week;
    printf("Enter number of days : ");
    scanf("%d", &in_days);
    if(in_days>1460){
        years = in_days/365;
        extra = in_days%365;
        months = cal_months(&extra);
        //days = extra%30;
        printf("%d days is same as %d years + %d months + %d days\n", in_days, years, months, extra);
    }else if(in_days<1460 && in_days>=365){
        years = in_days/365;
        extra = in_days%365;
        months = cal_months(&extra);
        //days = extra%30;
        printf("%d days is same as %d years + %d months + %d days\n", in_days, years, months, extra);
    }else if(in_days<365){
        days = in_days;
        months = cal_months(&days);
        printf("%d days is same as %d months + %d days\n", in_days, months, days);
    }else if(in_days<31){
        week= in_days/7;
        days = in_days%7;
        printf("%d days is same as %d weeks+ %d days\n", in_days, week, days);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This code is not taking care of LEAP year. you should add your own logic to include this functionality.